# change the font size of the selected value after it is being select in select element of html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the font of selected value in the select tag after the value has been selected .

Following is the code for my html

```
<select class="form-control" id="session-select">
    <option value="SELECT SESSION NUMBER" disabled selected>SELECT SESSION NUMBER</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
</select>
```

Following is the CSS

```
select{
            border:none !important;
            box-shadow: none;
            font-family: $lgr;
            font-size: 35px;
            height: 54px;
            @media (min-width: $mobile) and (max-width: $mobile-max){
            /* Media Query Between Screen 320px and 480px  */
                    font-size: 30px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can change the different font-size of option tags, but you can change color and background of selected option like in below demo.

#### Here is the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/99h7m/1/

#### Jquery

```
$('#session-select').on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).find('option[value='+val+']').css({
        'color':'red',
        'background':'#e8e8e8'
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks any way but that s the problem ,, i knew how to change the color but changing font is the problemo

Answer (score 0):

I attempted this in the following way and it worked for me:

Html Part:

```
  <select class="form-control" id="session-select">
    <option value="SELECT SESSION NUMBER" disabled selected id="selectedDd">SELECT SESSION NUMBER</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
  </select>
```

Jquery Part:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#session-select").change(function () {
        $("#session-select option").removeAttr("id");
        var selected = $("#session-select option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr('id','selectedDd');
    });
});
</script>
```

Css Part:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #session-select,#selectedDd {font-size:large!important; }
  option:not(#session-select){ font-size:small; } 
</style>
```